# Using gsettings to set wallpapers not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, gsettings

When I use this command:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///usr/share/backgrounds/TCP118v1_by_Tiziano_Consonni.jpg"
```

and then:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

It gave me the result :

```
'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/TCP118v1_by_Tiziano_Consonni.jpg'
```

which means the value of picture-uri was set successfully. But the wallpaper doesn't change. And I have tried the commands above under both root and normal user. But both have no effects. I can still change the wallpaper by manually right-clicking on the desktop. But I'd like to change it by gsettings in scripts. How Can I do that?

Other information.

```
$ unity --version
unity 7.4.0
$ gnome-session --version
$ nothing shows up
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any additional settings there ,like desktop icons disabled ? that affects whether or not wallpaper shows up as well. Also try using double quotes with single quotes like "'file:/...'"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loggign out and logging back in a gain after selecting the new file for you wallpaper? I was having the same issue and this fixed it for me.